# Typing table into R

Tags: r

I need help to type this table into R in order to do some analysis,

[image: [1]]

This is what I have done.

```
y=c(90,74,81,83,77,81,88,73, 98,72,87,85,99,79,87,80, 93,78,85,80,78,80,82,70, 95,76,83,86,90,75,84,80)
Replicate=rep(c("I","II"), each=16)
```

But then I don't know how to put in those a, b, interaction terms.

Comment: check with ftable

Comment: so I just put in Treatment =rep(c("(1)","a","b","ab","c","ac","bc","abc","d","ad","bd","abd","cd","acd","bcd","abcd"), times=2) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the following table as a list or a data frame as follows:

```
##Table shown as a list
l<-list(Treatment_combination= c("(1)", "a", "b", "ab", "c", "ac", "bc", "abc"),
 Replicate= data.frame(I= c(90,74,81,83,77,81,88,73), II=c(93,78,85,80,78,80,82,70)),
 Treatment_combination= c("d", "ad", "bd", "abd", "cd", "acd", "bcd", "abcd"),
 Replicate= data.frame(I= c(98,72,87,85,99,79,87,80), II=c(95,76,83,86,90,75,84,80)))

##Table shown as a data frame

as.data.frame(l)
```

Hope it will solve your query